# Verneinung eines Ausdrucks mit Wenn

Tags: phrase

Ich würde gerne wissen, wie man einen Ausdruck verneint, der wenn enthält. z.B.

> E := "Wenn ich Geld habe, dann kaufe ich mir einen Computer."

Comment: Was möchtest du verneinen? Eine Anwesenheit des Geldes  oder den Kauf eines Computers?

Comment: den ganzen Ausdruc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Den Regeln der [Aussagenlogik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussagenlogik) nach ist

> Ich habe Geld und kaufe mir keinen Computer

die Verneinung. Wenn-Sätze sind immer Implikationssätze.

> Wenn *P* dann *Q*

wird als

> *P* und nicht *Q*

verneint.

Answer (score 3):

> Wenn ich Geld habe, dann kaufe ich mir einen Computer.

Verneint:

> Wenn ich **kein** Geld habe, dann kaufe ich mir **keinen** Computer.

Als einfache Regel kannst du dir merken, dass *ein* zu *kein* wird, *eine* zu *keine*, *eines* zu *keines*, usw.

Beim *Geld* ist es etwas komplizierter, denn *das Geld* ist im Deutschen nicht abzählbar. Klingt seltsam, aber es gibt eben **nicht** *ein Geld, zwei Geld, drei Geld.* Solche Nomen führen auch keinen unbestimmten Artikel. Aber auch wenn man freiwillig keinen Artikel vor das Nomen setzen will: Will man es verneinen, kommt dennoch ein *kein* mit dem richtigen Geschlecht und Fall davor.

> Er geht Streit aus dem Weg.
>
> Er geht **keinem** Streit aus dem Weg.

---

Am besten wäre übrigens:

> **Falls** ich **kein** Geld habe, kaufe ich mir **keinen** Computer.

*Falls* habe ich statt *wenn* benutzt, weil es in der Verneinung nur noch um eine Schlussfolgerung gehen kann, nicht mehr um eine zeitliche Abfolge. Deshalb habe ich auch das *dann* weggelassen.

Comment: Klingt nach dem, was der OP sucht (dafür +1), nicht aber nach dem, was der tatsächlich geschrieben hat. Verneinung von "Wenn **A**, dann **B**" ist "**A** UND Verneinung (**B**)". Sonst verneint man nur A und B und vergiest man, dass dazwischen eine Implikationspfeile ist. Da wahrscheinlich meine Antwort sinken wird, und auch Benutzer bzw. Googler, nach dem was schriftlich steht, und nicht nach den Wünschen dieses OPs, suchen werden, lasse ich diesen Kommentar hier.

Comment: vielen Dank erst mal für die ausführliche Antwort. Leider ist Sie nicht korrekt, weil die erste Aussage "Ich habe Geld" eine hinreichende Bedingung für die zweite Aussage "Ich kaufe mir einen Computer" ist. Das heißt, wenn die 1.Aussage falsch ist, dann können wir daraus nicht folgern, dass die 2.Aussage falsch ist. Um das klarer zu machen, betrachten wir eine Situation, ich man kein Geld hat, aber man bekam einen Gutschein, mit dem man einen Computer kaufen kann. @c.p.'s Antwort ist korrekt

Comment: Ich war der Meinung, hier ginge es um Deutsch, nicht um Mathematik.

Comment: Die angegebene Verneinung im zweiten Zitat ist eine Schlussfolgerung aus der Vorlage, ändert bzw. verneint die Aussage aber nicht.

Comment: Der OP fragte: *Wie verneine ich den ganzen Ausdruck?* Die deutsche Sprache folgt wie praktisch alle anderen natürlichen Sprachen keiner formalen Logik, sondern ihrer eigenen inneren Logik. Ich werde jetzt zum ersten Mal eine Frage runterwerten, weil sie offensichtlich Off-topic ist.

Comment: Es geht um Deutsch. Wenn man Werke von Immanuel Kant, Nietsche, Goethe, .... liest, findet man zahlreiche Beispiele von Konstruktionen, die nach dieser Logik aufgebaut sind.

Comment: @AyoubFalah: Dann wäre sowohl dieser Hinweis als auch das Einfügen von ein oder zwei Zitaten ein deutlicher Gewinn für die Frage.

Comment: Das ist schwierig zu analysieren, wie Einige eine falsche Antwort hochwerfen. Nietzsche schrieb in Also Sprach Zarathustra: Dass jedermann schreiben und lernen darf, verdarb im Laufe der Zeit nicht nur das Denken sondern auch das Schreiben.

Answer (score 1):

Hiermit möchte ich eine ausführliche Erklärung geben, wie man @c.p´s Antwort herleiten kann.

> `E` := "Wenn ich Geld habe, dann kaufe ich mir einen Computer."

Seien A und B zwei Aussagen, mit

> `A` := "Ich habe Geld"
>
> `B` := "Ich kaufe mir einen Computer"

Der Ausdruck `E` hat die folgende Form: `Wenn A dann B`

`E` ist logisch equivalent zu `Wenn nicht A dann nicht B` und `nicht A oder B`, weil sie die gleiche Wahrheitstabelle haben.

Nun kann man `E` umformulieren, dass es git `E = nicht A oder B`

Nach dem De Morganschen Gesetz gilt es `nicht E = A und nicht B`

Also lautet die Verneinung von E folgendermaßen:

> "Ich habe Geld und ich kaufe mir keinen Computer."

Comment: Da fehlt aber das *Wenn*.

Comment: Die blauen "Formel"teile sind ohne definierten Operatorenvorrang, den es zwar für Programmiersprachen, nicht aber für Deutsch gibt, wenig hilfreich. Entweder man definiert: *nicht* bindet stärker als *und*, *und* bindet stärker als *oder*, oder man muss Klammern setzen.